# Spring LDAP TLS / SSL Exception: PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring, ssl, ssl-certificate, spring-ldap

Connecting to the LDAP server over TLS fails with the exception

```
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Failed to negotiate TLS session; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.processContextAfterCreation(AbstractTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.java:155)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:109)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:125)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:287)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:259)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:571)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:556)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:411)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:431)
```

I have checked the appropriate certificates are present in my key store and imported missing ones as described in [PKIX path building failed while making SSL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290570/pkix-path-building-failed-while-making-ssl-connection) however I am still getting the exception. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Nigel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the certificates produced by LDAP servers, this has been verified and issue now resolved.