# Getting sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error

Tags: java, rest, ssl-certificate, webservice-client

My application calls a web service in order to authenticate a specific user in that web service. That web service has their own self-signed CA certificate. I am using POST REST call to that service to authenticate a user by passing users 'username' and 'password' but then I am getting this error..

### javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have created a keystore and imported that servers certificate into that it. I am using that keystore in my application to trust the web service. Importing the certificate into JDK's cacerts can resolve my problem but this application can migrate to other servers according to clients requirement. So importing that certificate into jdk will not resolve the problem because that certificate has to be imported on that server too. So I have to trust it through my application code using that keystore. I searched many blogs and posts where everyone suggested to import that CA certificate into JDK's cacerts or to ignore the exception and blindly accept every CA certificate like this link [PKIX path building failed while making SSL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290570/pkix-path-building-failed-while-making-ssl-connection).

My error is very similar but none of the approach seem to work for me in this situation.
What I am doing in my application in order to authenticate a user is following and if there is any mistake in this approach then please correct me...

1. Created a keystore "authenticate.keystore"

   ```
   -imported the self-signed certificate into that keystore.
   ```
2. declared a static block that loads the keystore

   ```
   static{
   Properties properties;
   try {
   properties = new Properties();
   properties.load(Util.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
   System.out.println("Properties loaded successfully");
   } catch (IOException e) {
   properties = null;
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   String keyStore = Util.class.getClassLoader().getResource(properties.getProperty("KeyStoreLocation")).getFile();
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keyStore );
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
   System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs","com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
   Security.addProvider( (Provider)Class.forName("com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE").newInstance());
   Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
   }
   ```
3. Then Fetching users credentials from session and authenticating the client using REST call. Here I am using org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod

   ```
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("j_username");
   String password = (String) session.getAttribute("USER_PASSWORD");           
   PostMethod methodP = new PostMethod("location");
   method.addParameter("username", userName);
   method.addParameter("password", password);
   authenticateUser(method);
   ```
4. openning connection and trying to authenticate. I am using org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient

   ```
   public String authenticateUser(PostMethod method){
   try{
   final HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
   httpClient.executeMethod(method);
   if(statusCode==200)
   method.releaseConnection();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   method.releaseConnection();
   }        
   return null;
   }
   ```

But then while executing I am getting PKIX path binding error. Pasting the complete stacktrace below...

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1902)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1338)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.java:308)
at sysvana.helpdesk.HelperTicket.httpTicketGET(HelperTicket.java:238)
at sysvana.helpdesk.ActionHelpDeskBean.loadTickets(ActionHelpDeskBean.java:329)
at sysvana.helpdesk.ActionHelpDeskBean.getAllTickets(ActionHelpDeskBean.java:292)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:328)
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:273)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.invoke(AstMethodSuffix.java:65)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2508)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2129)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2077)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:286)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:244)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:670)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:45)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:280)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:92)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:99)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:255)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:204)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:534)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:607)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:359)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1207)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:97)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:90)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:54)
at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:5158)
at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1569)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:165)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:97)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:531)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePortletImpl.java:394)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:228)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:216)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:113)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:507)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:468)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:735)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:249)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:560)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:537)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:138)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:335)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:241)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:246)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:216)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1320)
... 210 more

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
... 216 more
```

I am very much stuck with this situation for a long time and really bugged by it. Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is here:

```
String keyStore = Util.class.getClassLoader().getResource(properties.getProperty("KeyStoreLocation")).getFile();
```

This has two problems:

1. The `URL.getFile()` method **does not** convert a `file:` URL into a filename.  That method returns the *path portion* of the URL.  Many characters that are legal in filenames must be escaped in a URL, in which case the raw path portion won't be an existing filename.  (Terminology explanation: In the early 90s, when the java.net.URL class was designed, it was common to refer to the path portion of a URL as the "file" because most URLs referred to physical files on remote systems, particularly `ftp:` URLs.)
2. If your class resides in a .jar file (and if it doesn't, it should), the URL isn't a `file:` URL at all;  it is a `jar:` URL.

`javax.net.ssl.trustStore` must point to a file, so if your class does reside in a .jar file, you can't convert the resource URL to a file at all.  You can, however, copy it to a file:

```
try (InputStream keystoreStream =
        Util.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
            properties.getProperty("KeyStoreLocation"))) {

    Path keystore = Files.createTempFile("keystore", ".jks");
    Files.copy(keystoreStream, keystore,
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case what was happening was my JRE version.
I am using eclipse x64 and my tomcat was using JRE x32, after i changed the Tomcat's JRE for the JRE inside my JDKx64 this error stopped to occur.

Comment: how you did this inside eclipse?