# How to get the content of this web page in java

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to find the contents of this page using Java.

> https://wordassociations.net/en/words-associated-with/cessation?button=Search

However, I get the error below. How can I resolve it

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

```
/*
 * SynonymFinder.java
 * 
 */    
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SynonymFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SynonymFinder obj = new SynonymFinder();

        System.out.println(get("https://wordassociations.net/en/words-associated-with/cessation?button=Search"));
    }

    public static String get(String url) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream()); sc.hasNext(); )
           sb.append(sc.nextLine()).append('\n');
        return sb.toString();
     }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PKIX path building failed while making SSL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290570/pkix-path-building-failed-while-making-ssl-connection)

Comment: (Also: [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshake Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore))

Comment: Possible duplicates [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

Answer (score 0):

your client doesn't have the certification, you should see this :
https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html